# Pandas set multiple line Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I use `read_csv` and want to drop some rows that have specific value, I could do it good in separate lines, but when I want to invoke both in same line, it returns a `NoneType` error.

My first code:

```
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
census_df.drop(census_df['SUMLEV'] == 40, inplace=True)
```

And I want to do:

```
census_df = (pd.read_csv('census.csv')
                 .drop(census_df['SUMLEV'] == 40, inplace=True))
```

It returned an error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need drop by `index` from `boolean indexing`:

```
census_df = ( pd.read_csv('census.csv').drop(census_df[(census_df['SUMLEV'] == 40)].index) )
```

But better is use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
census_df =  pd.read_csv('census.csv')
census_df = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] != 40]
```

Comment: Yes, I know the boolean way, I just want to apply it when I input data frame for clean code.
By the way, is it the boolean indexing is better performance than .drop?

Comment: I test it and with drop is slowier 2 times. `census_df = pd.DataFrame({'SUMLEV':[40,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (census_df)` and then `%timeit (census_df[(census_df['SUMLEV'] != 40)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 388 µs per loop` and `%timeit (census_df.drop(census_df[(census_df['SUMLEV'] == 40)].index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 723 µs per loop`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that drop returns None if it is instructed to be executed inplace (as suggested by the inplace operator). Remove the operator (which incurs some memory and processing cost) or do it in two lines.

Comment: After remove inplace, it ran, but got the wrong answer, it only dropped the first row of value 40.

Comment: Normally that should work, I have no idea what your code does differently, sorry. I would suggest opening a new question with more info

Comment: I have to drop the indexes of all the rows that have the values. Thanks.